# Add global values context in Node-Red through command line at start

Tags: javascript, node-red

I want to add information during call node-red from command line. The perfect solution will add data to Global context.

For now, I can launch node-red but I would like to add args for example a myIP arg :

```
node-red -myIP 10.100.10.1
```

I can modify red.js to get args and its value but I can't go further. I don't know how to set the parameters value to the global context.

I tried using functionGlobalContext but it doesn't work with data, only functions. More, I can't modify settings.js in command-line.

Any clue to continue ? It's not a problem to modify source code, I really need this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can set variables in `functionGlobalContext` in `settings.js` using environment variables

e.g.

```
 ...
 functionGlobalContext: {
    foo: process.env['MYIP']
 },
 ...
```

Then either export the environment variables before starting Node-RED:

```
 $ export MYIP="10.100.10.1"
 $ node-red
```

Or if it's just one env var you can inline it

```
 $ MYIP="10.100.10.1" node-red
```

Also you can just use environment variables directly in nodes' config as described [here](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/environment-variables).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even if I didn't use this, because I don't want to set Environment variables, you make me realise that I can access args with process.argv directly in a Node ! Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that some people want to use args during node-red call in terminal. So I'm sharing what I've done to do that. I'm working on Windows.

As I described above, I want this to be functionnal :

```
node-red -myIP 10.100.10.1
```

I want to get -myIP value (10.100.10.1) in a Node at the beginning to set it in the global context. This is particulary useful when you want to start node-red from a script (in my case in python).

To do this, I use the the [process api from nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv). This lead to have informations about process like the command-line arguments with process.argv. This return an array of each elements of the command-line that started the process :

```
process.argv ==> ['node-red', '-myIP', '10.100.10.1']
```

So you can do this in a node that is injected at the beginning and pass through this object and detect each arg you want and access to the next item to get the value. When you have the value of your argument, just set it in the global context for example :

```
global.set('IP', item)
```

And you have your command-line arg in a context. This could be used with any kind of scoped context (node, flow, global).